# How do I connect a TP-Link router to a network running proxy auto-configuration?

Tags: router, proxy

I have a cable bringing internet into my apartment. If I plug it into a single computer, to get the connection working I have to set the "Automatic Proxy Configuration" to point to a .pac file.

I have purchased a TP-Link router (model TL-WR741ND) and was hoping I could set it up to handle the "Automatic Proxy Configuration" so that computers connecting through the router would not have to take any additional steps to get the Internet working.

Can I set up the router to look for the .pac file so each computer does not have to be configured to do so? If so, how?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that router is going to do anything useful for you.  What you need is something that can run an HTTP proxy, forward requests to an upstream proxy, and can operate in interception mode.

Comment: Do you actually *have* Internet access? Or do you just have access to a web proxy?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I tell the difference?

Comment: Try a program other than a browser, like a torrent downloader, SSH client, FTP client, game that uses UDP, or anything not HTTP/HTTPS based.

Comment: I can't FTP in to anything : P